# Angular 2. Http. Subscribe: "this" pointer

Tags: angular, typescript

Got:

```
http.request('js/app/config/config.json').subscribe(data => {
            this.url = data.json().url;
        });
```

and somehow "this" points to Subscriber. Don't know why... cause I thought that fat-arrow lambda will catch parent's class pointer.

Why so?

Comment: You can see in the playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground) that `this` has correct value: http://bit.ly/1ZXO53U

Comment: @shtpavel, check my answer and refer the doc mentioned in the answer.

Comment: d.pr/i/iBa check this out.. what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

Based on the screenshot : http://d.pr/i/iBa

[image]

You are debugging `this` in the console. Please note that `this` on the console will be the **actual this**. When TypeScript generates an arrow function for non ES6 JavaScript (which doesn't have native support for arrow functions) `this` is mapped to `_this` (and other things) which means that you need to view `_this`.

## TIP

Just debug the generated JavaScript when learning TypeScript. This is the TypeScript bug : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2859 if you are interested.

Answer (score 3):

I found a workaround, you can try this

```
http.request('js/app/config/config.json').subscribe((function (data) {
  this.url = data.json().url;
}).bind(this));
```

Answer (score 2):

**Arrow functions do not have their own `this` value.** The value of `this` inside an arrow function is always inherited from the enclosing scope, in your case `Subscriber`.

In the ES6 version, note that the `subscribe` method receives `this` from its caller. The inner function is an arrow function, so it inherits **`this`** from the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's ES6 Arrow Function Feature to avoid creating one more variable for the context. You Can’t Override An Arrow Function’s "this".

```
http.request('js/app/config/config.json').subscribe(function(data) {
  this.url = data.json().url;
});
```

Refer this doc:
http://derickbailey.com/2015/09/28/do-es6-arrow-functions-really-solve-this-in-javascript/

Comment: Maybe you didn't understand.. I know what arrow function means. But "this" inside lambda points not to the class. Check this out: http://d.pr/i/iBa

Comment: can u share the whole getCompanies method in question